# What are the steps to prepare and use moment-timezone.js with a subset of zones and years

Tags: javascript, momentjs

After installing moments-timezone with bower:

I see there are packed and unpacked versions of latest timezone data.

In moment-timezone.js I see there is a place holder // INJECT DATA where I presume I'm supposed to insert the packed version of the data I'm interested in.

I see I have the moment-timezone-utils.js with methods to pack/unpack/filter data.

Am I supposed to use all this in order to offline prepare my required version of the data, and than insert the output result instead of the  // INJECT DATA place holder?

**Update:**

Since the "Data" section in Moment home page is currently "Coming soon..." What I currently did is manually running offline:

```
JSON.stringify(moment.tz.filterLinkPack(unpackedBundle, startYear, endYear));
```

I took the *unpackedBundle* json object from the \data\unpacked folder.

And then loaded the result into moment-timezone in my java script code.

```
moment.tz.load(filteredLinkedPackedBundle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [the Data Loading documentation](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/adding-a-zone/).  The `moment.tz.add` and `moment.tz.link` methods can be used to load individual zones and linke, or you can use `moment.tz.load` to load JSON data containing multiple zones.

Use the packed versions of the data, from [/data/packed](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/tree/develop/data/packed) in the repo.  `latest.json` has the entire data file for the current release.  You can edit this file to remove the information you don't care about.

The easiest way though is to just use one of the files from [the moment-timezone main page](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) that already contain data.

[image: website]

- `moment-timezone.js` contains no data, just the script.  Use with the functions described above.
- `moment-timezone-2010-2020.js` contains the script, and the data for all time zones, truncated to include changes only for recent years.
- `moment-timezone-all-years.js` contains the script, and the time zone data for all time zones for all years.  It is essentially the same as using the `moment-timezone.js` file, and loading the `latest.json` data bundle.

You do not need to modify the script itself, as the data can be loaded separately.  The `// INJECT DATA` comment in the script is just a placeholder for moment-timezone's build process to know where to place the data when building the files for the website.

Comment: So in case I want to filter out some time zones, and filter them by years, I still have to manually prepare my required unpacked bundle json manually?

Comment: If you just want to truncate zones, you can easily modify the packed data file manually.  It's just harder to do that when truncating years, so the tooling in `filterLinkPack` is probably easier.

Comment: I'd still go through `moment.tz.load` rather than internally calling `loaddata`.  They do the same thing, but there's no need to modify the script.